# Setting up a secure webserver

Tags: security, hosting, web-hosting

So I have finished creating my first website that I will be hosting online. It have php, html, and javascript. Now I am looking for a way to host my website securely. I have looked at sites like [godaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/) and [web hosting hub](http://www.webhostinghub.com/cnet-offer.html?utm_expid=31925339-16.qZArX0L5Q6e57DBbZYvTxw.0&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Freviews.cnet.com%2Fweb-hosting-plans%2F). I was wondering what the best hosting service would be for my needs.

My needs:

- Able to run php
- Have a actual name, like www.noahhuppert.com
- Be able to obscure the code so people can not just copy it(This is because my website is for my website design company and I have examples of templates people can use, but I don't want people jsut stealing those templates with a simple right click + inspect element)
- Run server side scripts(Like slowing down connections to users if they fail to login too many times, to prevent brute force cracking attempts)
- Deny access to people reading files(I don't want people downloading my password hash files or anything like that)
- Be able to host files on the services servers, I don't just want a dns pointing back to my computer.

Comment: ...and your question is? I can guess though that it's not a good fit for this site.

Comment: @deceze And I quote "I was wondering what the best hosting service would be for my needs."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is asking for an opinion. Basically any linux web host will provide most of what you're looking for. You're asking for an opinion about which hosting site is the best. I cannot answer that.

What I do want to warn you about is this:

From your question, you're concerned with:
- security

this is not a web host provider feature, but a feature of secure web code. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013 for great introduction to website security.

- obscure code

You cannot prevent someone from stealing your css. They will not get to your raw templates (I'm assuming you're using templates) if you set your file permissions right on the web server.

- if you're concerned with brute force protections, you'll need to code that up yourself. The web host provider would not (and should not) rate limit your connections.

Comment: Thanks, I have already written the "anti-brute force" code I just need a thing to host it. And I guess your right, without my html the css would be useless.